# Multiple conclusions(formulas) in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I have a table with the values:

- 0
- 100
- 200
- 300

In the next coloumn I have data entry cell of 250. 
Underneath the 250 I would like a formula that says:

- If 250 is less than 100 but more than 0, "A"
- If 250 is less than 200 but more than 100, "B"
- If 250 is less than 300 but more than 200, "C"

Based on that formula, the cell below would automatically be "C"

How do I create that formula?

Comment: this would most likely need to be done in VBA

Comment: I edited the first condition of the formula. If my change was incorrect, please rollback the edit. http://superuser.com/posts/630070/revisions

Answer (score 1):

LOOKUP can be used here, i.e.

`=LOOKUP(C1,A1:A4,{"A","B","C","Error"})`

That returns Error if C1 >= 300, you didn't say what you want in that case......

Comment: Formula golf! Awesome!

Comment: Pretty cool, I'd put the results in the column next to the lookup value =LOOKUP(C1,A1:A4,B1:B4)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for the `IF` and `AND` functions. I don't have Excel handy, but try this:

```
=IF(AND(A1>0;A1<100);"A";IF(AND(A1>100;A1<200);"B";IF(AND(A1>200;A1<300);"C";"")))
```

The format is `=IF(condition;true-value;false-value)`. In this case, the `condition` is a call to `AND()`, and `false-value` is another (similar) IF statement. I hope I got the number of paranthesises right. Paste the above into a cell other than A1, then adjust the value in A1 and see if it does what you want. If not, adjust the conditions accordingly. Once you get it working the way you want it for one cell, just range-fill the entire range.

Using `IF` gets unwieldy very quickly if you have long lists of conditions, though. If you find yourself with more than 2-3 levels of IFs, it's probably better to consider the possibility of using VBA instead, which is much easier to structure in a readable fashion.

For some more examples, you may want to consider [*How to use nested IF statements in Excel with AND, OR, NOT* on the Experiments in Finance blog](http://www.experiglot.com/2006/12/11/how-to-use-nested-if-statements-in-excel-with-and-or-not/).

I also took a guess that your first bullet point was supposed to be the range 0 to 100, since no number will simultaneously be less than 0 and more than 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` and `CHOOSE` pretty efficiently here. Where `A1:A4` are the values to compare against and `C1` is the data entry cell:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4,1),"A","B","C")
```